# Writing pandas column to csv without merging integers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have extracted **user_id** against **shop_ids** as pandas dataframe from database using SQL query.

```
    user_id     shop_ids
0   022221205   541
1   023093087   5088,4460,4460,4460,4460,4460,4460,4460,5090
2   023096023   2053,2053,2053,2053,2053,2053,2053,2053,2053,1...
3   023096446   4339,4339,3966,4339,4339
4   023098684   5004,3604,5004,5749,5004
```

I am trying to write this dataframe into csv using:
`df.to_csv('users_ordered_shops.csv')`

I end up with the csv merging the shop ids into one number as such:

```
    user_id     shop_ids
0   22221205    541
1   23093087    508,844,604,460,446,000,000,000,000,000,000,000
2   23096023    2,053,205,320,532,050,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000
3   23096446    43,394,339,396,643,300,000
4   23098684    50,043,604,500,457,400,000
```

The values for index `2` are:

```
print(df.iloc[2].shop_ids)
2053,2053,2053,2053,2053,2053,2053,2053,2053,1294,1294,2053,1922
```

Expected output is a csv file with all shop_ids intact in one column or different columns like:

```
    user_id     shop_ids
0   022221205   541
1   023093087   5088,4460,4460,4460,4460,4460,4460,4460,5090
2   023096023   2053,2053,2053,2053,2053,2053,2053,2053,2053,1294,1294,2053,1922
3   023096446   4339,4339,3966,4339,4339
4   023098684   5004,3604,5004,5749,5004
```

Any tips on how to get the shop ids without merging when writing to a csv file? I have tried converting the shop_ids column using `astype()` to `int` and `str` which has resulted in the same output.

Comment: Please avoid images, replace them by data in plain text to be usable by other people. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Corralien. Just edited the images to text.

Comment: What is your expect output? For index 2 for example

Comment: Expected output would be a csv file that doesnt lose the shop_ids or merge the shop_ids into one long number when converting to csv.

Comment: You need to show what code you are using.  I can't understand how you are changing 4 digit numbers to 3 digit numbers.  It seems you are merging the numeric strings or taking the string and removing commas manually.

Comment: I've written the command I have used to write the dataframe to csv. Using the df.to_csv() command itself turns the digits this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

To get one shop per column (and remove duplicates), you can use:

```
pd.concat([df['user_id'],
           df['shop_ids'].apply(lambda x: sorted(set(x.split(','))))
                         .apply(pd.Series)],
          axis=1).to_csv('users_ordered_shops.csv', index=False)
```

---

Change the delimiter. Try:

```
df.to_csv('users_ordered_shops.csv', sep=';')
```

Or change the quoting strategy:

```
import csv

df.to_csv('users_ordered_shops.csv', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
```

Comment: Changing the delimiter does separate most of the values but merges the user_id and first shop_id value together. Changing quoting strategy has no change in the output.

Comment: Try: `pd.concat([df['user_id'], df['shop_ids'].apply(lambda x: sorted(set(x.split(',')))).apply(pd.Series)], axis=1).to_csv('data.csv', index=False)`

Comment: @ Corralien this worked for me! It got the unique values in different columns. Could you add this in your answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Great. thanks for the help!